# How to run expo (react native) app on cloudfoundry (e.g. IBM Cloud)?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, expo

When running expo locally, by using:

```sh
yarn start
```

You will get a QR code or a URL which you can open on expo app. There're 3 URLs you can choose:

1. Tunnel
2. LAN
3. Local

My question is, how do I do the same by hosting somewhere else? I tried to do `export` but by looking at `dist` folder, there're no index.html file. Or another file will be the main file instead?

I'm trying to host it as static in cloudfoundry-based like IBM Cloud / Bluemix.

Please advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the text available at https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/distribution/hosting-your-app/ , you are not expected to produce a final "web application" that can be accessed via a regular web browser. Instead you provide the static content that can be used by an "Expo" client.

```
$ ls -1d dist/*
dist/android-index.json
dist/assets
dist/bundles
dist/ios-index.json
```

What you are expected to serve, is the android/ios-index.json files and the assest/bundles.